# Print only seconds for unix time columns in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, unix-timestamp, pretty-print

Here's a snippet that loads a partial candlestick data into a Pandas DataFrame. What interests me is to pretty print the content of the DataFrame. I want that the two millisecond unix time stamp columns are displayed in seconds.

Here's the raw data:

```
rawData = {'t': 1525019820000, 'T': 1525019879999, 'o': '0.07282300', 'c': '0.07290700', 'h': '0.07293300', 'l': '0.07279800', 'v': '48.57300000'}
```

This code outputs a full date for each time stamp column:

```
import pandas as pd

rawData = {'t': 1525019820000, 'T': 1525019879999, 'o': '0.07282300', 'c': '0.07290700', 'h': '0.07293300', 'l': '0.07279800', 'v': '48.57300000'}

df = pd.DataFrame([rawData])
df['t'] = pd.to_datetime(df['t'], unit='ms') # converting unix ts to datetime
df['T'] = pd.to_datetime(df['T'], unit='ms')
print(df.to_string(justify='center', columns=['t','T','o','c','h','l','v'], header=['from','to','open','close','high','low','vol']))
```

Output:

```
          from                   to               open       close        high        low         vol     
0 2018-04-29 16:37:00 2018-04-29 16:37:59.999  0.07282300  0.07290700  0.07293300  0.07279800  48.57300000
```

How can I display only the time part of the two time columns, getting that instead ?

```
    from      to        open       close        high        low         vol     
0 16:37:00 16:37:59  0.07282300  0.07290700  0.07293300  0.07279800  48.57300000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `formatters` parameter ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html)):

```
print(df.to_string(justify='center', columns=['t','T','o','c','h','l','v'],
                   formatters={'t': lambda x: '{:%H:%M:%S}'.format(pd.to_datetime(x, unit="D")),
                               'T': lambda x: '{:%H:%M:%S}'.format(pd.to_datetime(x, unit="D"))},
                   header=['from','to','open','close','high','low','vol']))
```

Comment: Yes, this the solution I was writing while you post your answer. Thank you for your reactivity !

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the formatters= parm of the DataFrame.to_string method. as documented [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html). Lambdas are defined in the formatters dictionary, keyed by raw column names ...

```
formatters={'t': lambda x: x.strftime("%H:%M:%S"), 'T': lambda x: x.strftime("%H:%M:%S")}
```

and here's the whole code:

```
import pandas as pd

rawData = {'t': 1525019820000, 'T': 1525019879999, 'o': '0.07282300', 'c': '0.07290700', 'h': '0.07293300', 'l': '0.07279800', 'v': '48.57300000'}

df = pd.DataFrame([rawData])
df['t'] = pd.to_datetime(df['t'], unit='ms')
df['T'] = pd.to_datetime(df['T'], unit='ms')
print(df.to_string(justify='center', columns=['t','T','o','c','h','l','v'], header=['from','to','open','close','high','low','vol'],  formatters={'t': lambda x: x.strftime("%H:%M:%S"), 'T': lambda x: x.strftime("%H:%M:%S")}))
```

which outputs

```
    from      to        open       close        high        low         vol     
0 16:37:00 16:37:59  0.07282300  0.07290700  0.07293300  0.07279800  48.57300000
```